# Mount an external disk in write mode from recovery console on MacBook Pro 2012, Catalina

Tags: external-disk, single-user

I deleted a partition of my mac and may have to recover my passwords from a file on the disk.

I want to make a disk image to allow later recovery and reinstall the system, but I can't mount an external disk in write mode.

I tried to mount the disk using the command:

```
mount -t ntfs -o rw disk13s2 /Volumes/ext/
```

However, the disk is only mounted read only.

[The command `csrutil disable`](https://www.hawkdive.com/block-or-disable-usb-storage-devices-on/#disable-SIP) is not available.

How can I mount my external disk in write mode so I can make a disk image?

Comment: Wy do you would use a NTFS disk to save your data? Your actual system is Catalina?  Can you open a new terminal (cmd+n) and open Safari with the command ```/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/macOS/Safari``` Then in the first terminal you do ```diskutil list internal```then you add the result at your question.

Comment: Would use NTFS disk because it's what I have available.

I updated to Catalina, but it seems recovery system is still 10.8.5.

Comment: It's not possible write on NTFS disk from Recovery. But it's possible reformat the external disk in JHFS or APFS and use it. This requires reformatting the disk and lose any data present on it.